# buffer overflow during memory reallocation

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc, buffer-overflow

I was making a C program to convert 12 hour clock into 24 hour clock with the format of input being HH:MM:SSAM or HH:MM:SSPM and 24hr clock output being HH:MM:SS

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *time = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%11s", time);
    if (time[8] == 'A' || time[8] == 'P')
    {

        if (time[8] == 'A')
        {
            time = realloc(time, (9 * sizeof(char)));                
            printf("%s\n", time);
        }
        else
        {
            time = realloc(time, (8 * sizeof(char)));                
            char str[3];
            sprintf(str, "%c%c", time[0], time[1]);
            int hours;
            hours = atoi(str);
            int milhours;
            milhours = hours + 12;
            char milstr[3];
            sprintf(milstr, "%d", milhours);
            time[0] = milstr[0];
            time[1] = milstr[1];
            printf("%s\n", time);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("give a standard format\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is no compilation error,but the program doesnt run because of buffer overflow. When I reduce the size of dnamic array `time` , is it necessary that the last 2 elements of `time` will be removed?

EDIT: I updated `time`, `str` and `milstr` for `NULL` terminator and the buffer overflow problem is resolved. Thanks for the recommended reading!

Comment: why would you call `free(time)` after realloc?

Comment: Allocate +1 for NUL terminator.

Comment: If really using a C compiler, just remove all those useless cast, they aren't needed nor recommended in any way.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition.

Comment: `time` is a commonly used identifier, better use your own.

Comment: @alk by cast you mean `atoi()` function?

Comment: No, I mean the `char*` like in `(char*)malloc(...`

Comment: `atoi()` is unreliable as well, as it does not provide error checking, better use `strtol()`.

Comment: If the original size of the variable is 10 bytes, why bother shrinking it to 8 bytes? Do 2 bytes make any significant difference?

Comment: To define a C-"string" with N characters allocate N+1. Mind the `0`-terminator.

Comment: in 24hr clock output I need `HH:MM:SS` so i shrink it to 8 bytes

Comment: as @BLUEPIXY says, your inital malloc isn't big enough. You need 11 bytes to hold `HH:MM:SSAM` plus the NULL terminator.

Comment: Taking unlimited user input like here `scanf("%s",...` introduces the risk of overflowing the input buffer, better do `scanf("%9s", ...`. Again: Mind the `0`-terminator.

Comment: you do not need to shrink the buffer to the exact size. The end of a C string  is defined by the null ('\0') not by length. THis is your error, you do not allow space for the null, your strpintf to str has the same problem, you need 3 chars not 2

Comment: you could refactor this by pulling the identical realloc() calls out (above) the inner if/else, and the moving the identical printf() outside (below), and then you have an empty if() {} block which could then be removed.

Comment: Here `atoi(str);` you pass the address of the 1st element to 2-element-sized `char`-array. `atoi()` expects a C-"string", which `str` isn't. Again^2 : Mind the `0`-terminator.

Comment: @kartikeykant18 HH:MM:SS+ NUL = 8 +1. HH:MM:SSAM+NUL = 10+1, `char str[2];` --> `char str[2+1];`, `char milstr[2];` --> `char milstr[2+1];`

Comment: Here `sprintf(milstr, "%d", milhours);` you (most likely) print 2 bytes into a 2-element-sized char-array, where you need 3 bytes. The third is for ... you name it: The `0`- terminator.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1990/strings#t=20170113205737796223

Comment: Editing your question in place is not a good idea after comments and/or questions have been given as such edits may render the answers/comment und-understandable. Better add edits as updates/additions to your question.

Comment: `scanf("%11s", time);` --> `scanf("%10s", time);` and You forgot one as `time = realloc(time, (8 * sizeof(char)));`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `null` terminator is not something inputted by the user, is that why?

Comment: when i shrink the size of `time` using realloc does it remove the last 2 elements inputted by the user i.e. AM or PM?

Comment: like `scanf("%10s", time);` and `sprintf(str, "%c%c", time[0], time[1]);` add it at the end.

Comment: Although it is not necessarily deleted, it can not be used.

Comment: but in output it prints out PM or AM, rest is correct

Comment: So, It is necessary to modify the program. E.g `time[8] = 0;
            printf("%s\n", time);`

Comment: If `realloc` changes memory size successfully, the new memory block may be another location or may be the original address. In any case do not access the part exceeding the specified size. Do not expect that the shrunk part will be initialized with 0. 
Probably not like that.

Comment: So, seems no one told you that your code has a classic bug. i.e. `x = realloc(x, ...);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133143/discussion-on-question-by-kartikeykant18-buffer-overflow-during-memory-reallocat).

Answer (score 3):

> EDIT: I updated time, str and milstr for NULL terminator and the buffer overflow problem is resolved. Thanks for the recommended reading!

You still have problems.

```
char *time = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%11s", time);
```

That `malloc` allocates 11 bytes, but that `scanf` needs ***12***. That's because C strings are terminated with a null byte, you always need to allocate one more byte.

---

As for all the reallocating you're doing, it seems like you're doing that to truncate the string. That's overkill for 3 bytes, and it won't truncate anyway. Because `realloc` may return the same pointer, you can't expect that shrinking will zero the following memory and truncate the string. You can't expect it when it returns a different pointer either, or when it grows memory. Only with `calloc` can you be certain that the allocated memory has been zeroed.

Instead, skip the `realloc` and stick a null byte in to truncate the string.

```
if (time[8] == 'A')
{
    time[8] = '\0';
    puts(time);
}
```

`time` is still 12 bytes (once the `malloc` has been fixed), but the null byte tells C to stop reading at `time[8]`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I found out these problems maybe at the same time you were, and I fixed those, my main issue was buffer overflow though which I got an idea through comments :)